# Function called for every event Angular 9

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-changedetection, router-outlet, templatebinding

I'm using lazy loading structure for my angular project. I have using property binding using a function call in my template. The issue is, whenever I click anywhere on page, this function is called. Below I have shared my code.

**app-component.html code**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet> 
<div [style]="hello()">Hello world</div>
```

**app-component.ts code**

```
hello() { 
  console.log('testing>>>>>');   
  return `color:red`; 
}
```

Each and every time with click event, **hello()** is called.

**Note:** When I remove/comment *`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`*, it functions normal.

What could be the root cause of this problem.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its actually not the the router that does it. Its the redraw that does it. Be careful with running functions in your template code. Instead you should use pure pipes as they are memorized. But in your case i would just bind the color variable on ngStyle instead. I am guessing you need the color to be dynamic for some reason. And hence you change change that value with a property instead.

Comment: Thank you Henrik Bøgelund Lavstsen. Here Iam using [style] for just an example. The actual issue is Whatever items I had tried to bind with property syntax, this triggering happens. For example, I have parent-child component:
<child-component [someProperty]=hello()></child-component>
This time also the same issue happens.
Assume, hello() returns some values.

Answer (score 0):

The function is fired on redraw and not the router-outlet. You should avoid using functions in your template. If should be a pure pipe for those cases or bind to variables in your typescript code.

Here i have example where you would get the same issue. It will also fire just by pressing the click button even though nothing happends. It triggers the redraw.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9aeje5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

hello-component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1 [style]="ohNo()">Hello {{name}}!</h1><button (click)="anyAction()">click</button>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;

  ohNo() {
    console.log('i fire on redraw');
    return 'color:red';
  }
  anyAction() {}
}
```

if you need to change the color via some functionality you can have it bound to a variable

```
<p [ngStyle]="{
  color: appColor
}">
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
```

and in your code .ts file have

```
appColor = 'red';
```

Comment: Here Iam using [style] for just an example. The actual issue is Whatever items I had tried to bind with property syntax([]), this triggering happens. For example, I have parent-child component: <child-component [someProperty]=hello()></child-component> This time also the same issue happens. Assume, hello() returns some values.

Comment: In this case. Bind an object to the child and not a function. You can use set change dection to onPush then it will not trigger redraws unless a new object has been set.

Comment: Issue still persists even after adding ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Comment: Did you convert code away from a function in your template binding ? If its impossible yo do without you will need to create a pipe for it

Comment: Function is needed. The actual scenario is explained below.
Parent component: VehicleComponent.
Child component: MaintenanceComponent
Need to pass some data to the child. So I use <app-maintenance [maintenance]="getInfo()"></app-maintenance>. 
getInfo() is defined in the parent component. getInfo() is called every time I have clicked on the page. This is the real usecase.